# How to not show changes done with jQuery (document ready) on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im quite new to jQuery and Javascript in general. I really like what you can achieve with this- but Im having a question. Im using document ready to change a string of text inside a DIV. When the page loads, it first show the old text and when the DOM is ready, change it according to the script. I understand why this is happening - But what are the correct way to do this if you dont want to see the old string?

Comment: Hide it with css and change & show it with js?

Comment: Thats a possibility.. Is this the way people usually do it then?

Comment: You should change the string in html so you dont need to change it with js if possible.

Comment: Im using this in wordpress - and I dont wanna change something that I would lose on an update. since my theme has a custom JS window, this is more convenient. I also are curious on whats the correct practise is for things like this.

Comment: Maybe there is a hook/filter to change the text in wordpress functions.php. Otherwise you need to do something like what i told you in first answer. Maybe a lot of other javascripts executing before your document ready. Maybe you could try to include/run your js before other scripts to make it change the text earlier?